# Get class name of child element on mouseover jquery

Tags: jquery, get, classname

When hovering over the menuItem list i want the subMenu to display then mouseout hide again. Question is how do i target the specific subMenu (assuming i'll have more menu items with submenus) within the menuItem clicked.

html

```
<ul>
 <li class="menuItem">
 Menu Item 1
 <ul class="subMenu">
 <li> <a href="#"> Link 1 </a> </li>
 <li> <a href="#"> Link 2 </a> </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.menuItem').mouseover(function() {


$($this).class('.subMenu').show();

});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$('.menuItem').hover(
    function(){
        // first function is for the mouseover/mouseenter events
        $(this).find('.subMenu').show();
    },
    function(){
        // second function is for mouseleave/mouseout events
        $(this).find('.subMenu').hide();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8pu3K/).

It's worth pointing out that you don't need to use JavaScript at all for this (unless you're having to support browsers such as IE6 and below), and could use just CSS:

```
.menuItem:hover .subMenu,
.subMenu:hover {
    display: list-item;
}
.subMenu {
    display: none;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8pu3K/1/).

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: Use toggle() instead of calling hover() twice:
$('.menuItem').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.subMenu').toggle();
});

Comment: Why? I'm calling `hover()` once. ...unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I meant instead of using an explicit mouseleave function. toggle() shows hidden, and hides visible elements, so toggle() should be enough.

Comment: I prefer to explicitly undo the things I do, if that makes sense. It can make for more repetitious scripting, but it tends to reduce the scope for unanticipated events. Plus, in this case, means I don't have to worry about siblings, and their children, to the `.menuItem` elements.

Comment: Nothing in your comment is different with toggle() instead of the two methods you use. But it comes down to personal preference. I just like my code to be as clean and short as possible.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different version of David Thomas' solution, which uses [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and only one inner function:

```
$('.menuItem').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.subMenu').toggle();
});
```

Since you just want to show or hide `.subMenu`, you only need one inner function, which is called on mouse-over and mouse-leave. It's probably a matter of personal preference if you like to explicitly write the mouse-leave function, but I like this shorter version.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(this).find('.subMenu').show();
```

instead of:

```
$($this).class('.subMenu').show();
```

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation for your answer?  It might help the OP understand a little bit better.